# .htaccess causes lots of page visits

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am creating an admin page just to count page visits and some other things. I have a rewriterule to turn www.mysite.com/asd to www.mysite.com/index.php?page=asd.

If I visit any of my pages, it works fine, it adds One visit to the database using the php code I submit below. However, when loading my admin page, it immidately adds 18 (every time 18) visits. The admin page is located in a subfolder named 'admin'. I tried removing the .htaccess content, and then the issue no longer appears, so I'm 99% sure this is somehow related to my .htaccess file. (it did still add 1 visit when loading the index page).

I have this php code to count visits:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO views(page, timestamp) VALUES(:page, :time)" );
$stmt->execute( array( ":page" => $file, ":time" => $timestamp ) );
```

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: what is `$file`?

Comment: Does the admin page load things like style sheets and JavaScript files? What about images? All of those things may be getting rewritten depending on how they are actually coded in your admin page.